# What to use to Push/Commit changes from desktop to cpanel

Tags: version-control, cpanel, commit

I'm working on code on my desktop and would like the ability to push/commit my changes straight to the live version of the WordPress site I've got running on an inMotion hosting account online.

Any programs/batch files that would allow a simple procedure to commit changes to the files/upload new ones if I changed anything on my local code to the live hosting version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IDE (having FTP ability) like PHPStorm, set up a FTP account on your hosting account & then can simply configure PHPStorm with that FTP so that everytime you do changes on your local desktop, it will commit changes on your hosting account.